# Warning about pandas.Series.asType copy=True option

Tags: python, pandas, copy

In the [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) function, there is warning about setting the option `copy = True`, precisely *`"be really careful with this"`*.

Does anyone know why the emphatic warning?

Comment: I think the danger is if you explicitly pass `copy=False` it may not operate inplace. I doubt this will work all the time, I'm surprised this param remains, most of these have been mopped up and changed to `inplace` which also maybe deprecated due to confusion surrounding this. I'd post a question on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) about this as it could be a legacy param